# trying to add marshmallow permissions using "Permissions Dispatcher"

Tags: java, android, plugins, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to use the plugin Permissions Dispatcher(https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher) to handle Marshmallow runtime permissions in a GPSTracker class which I want to call in a fragment, but I'm still getting the error "Call requires permission that may be rejected by user: Code should explicitly check to see if permission is available..."  I think I need to add something to MainActivity but I can't figure out what.

**GPSTracker.java**

```
package me.paxana.alerta.adapter;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import permissions.dispatcher.NeedsPermission;
import permissions.dispatcher.RuntimePermissions;

@RuntimePermissions
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {


    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    @NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    @NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package me.paxana.alerta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import me.paxana.alerta.adapter.SlidingMenuAdapter;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment1;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment2;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment3;
import me.paxana.alerta.model.ItemSlideMenu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<ItemSlideMenu> listSliding;
    private SlidingMenuAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listViewSliding;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            //check to see if user is logged in
            if (currentUser == null) {
                navigateToLogin();  //if not, send them to the login page
            }

        else {  //if they are, send the username to the log (debug only)
                Log.i(TAG, currentUser.getUsername());
            }

        listViewSliding = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_sliding_menu);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listSliding = new ArrayList<>();
        //add item for sliding list
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_settings, "Map"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_about, "Emergency Call"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_account_plus_black_48dp, "Friends"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_logout_black_48dp, "Log Out"));

        adapter = new SlidingMenuAdapter(this, listSliding);
        listViewSliding.setAdapter(adapter);

        //display icon to open/close slider
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //item selected
        listViewSliding.setItemChecked(0, true);
        //close menu
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
        //handle on item click
        //at some point it may make sense to change this to sort by item ID instead of position
        listViewSliding.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 3) {
                    ParseUser.logOut();
                    navigateToLogin();
                } else {

                    //replace fragment
                    replaceFragment(position);
                    //item selected
                    listViewSliding.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    //close menu
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
                }
            }

        });

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    }

    private void navigateToLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        //these flags remove the mainactivity from the history, so you can't back your way into mainactivity from the login screen
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
//create method replace fragment
    private void replaceFragment(int position) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
        }
        if(null != fragment) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer of PermissionsDispatcher.
It seems you don't follow the usage of the library. I recommend to look at sample code. 
You have to use generated class by annotation processing.
https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher/tree/master/sample

Comment: hey Shintaro nice Library but please help us by providing code for location permissions ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. We are facing a lot of problem in doing this.

Comment: There is nothing special. Could u check below code? 

https://github.com/konifar/droidkaigi2016/blob/a92ae2dc943e97243d9eea5b00f66382e8fc86e9/app/src/main/java/io/github/droidkaigi/confsched/fragment/MapFragment.java#L115

Comment: @ShintaroKatafuchi I am trying to add ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION for support background scanning on Android 10 devices but it's not working. How could I add these both permission on my method where I start background location scanning?I think there is no way to add more than one permission on single method but how could I achieve this? Currently it's just showing two options and not all three with "Always allow". You help is appreciated.